# Python crop area bounded with thin white rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have to crop 2048x1024 image to get 1440x720 image. Cropped image should be part of original image inside thin white rectangle. I am uploading photo as attachment. I tried using threshold and contours but it cropped part of animals on the photo because they are also white.

[image: image that should be cropped]

Comment: Please include your code (as text not a picture) in your post so we can see what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = np.array(Image.open('animals.jpeg'))

thresh, pix_marg = 1.5, 2
for ang in range(4):
    t = np.sum(img[0]) * thresh
    for i, c in enumerate(img):
        if np.sum(c) > t:
            break
    img = np.rot90(img[i+pix_marg:])
    
Image.fromarray(img)
```

[image: animals]

Comment: please review [answer] and explain the operation of your code.

Comment: I am aware of that page